# Is this the ascii value of a character?

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I would like to understand what is happening here in the last statement

```
std::string a_string = "Hello";
uint64_t          hash = 0x...;
hash  = hash ^ a_string.at(0);
```

I understand in the last statement an operation is being performed on the basis of the character H. Is my understanding correct here the ascii value of H is returned which undergoes an exclusive or with the value of hash. ?

Comment: Is hash given a value somewhere between the second and last lines?

Comment: Yes hash has a value assigned. Sorry I did not mention it here. Ill update that value.

Comment: Yes/No Question ? Ans - Yes . Please see `std::basic_string::at` reference

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a Yes/No questionnaire

Comment: It would be the "ASCII value" only if the compiler's target execution character set if ASCII, which isn't likely. _You_ control that, but have probably left it as the default, maybe [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Try it with "§1: Salutations". (§ is not in the ASCII character set.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, <strike>but `hash` is (was) used uninitialized, which causes undefined behaviour.</strike>

Comment: Looks like he assigned it

Comment: @P0W it wasn't in the original post though ;)